# How can I use a GUID as ID in CosmosDB when I insert data from Azure Streaming Job

Tags: sql, azure, streaming, azure-cosmosdb, azure-eventhub

Hi I have a Azure Streaming Job that takes data from an Event Hub and inserts them in a CosmosDB Database. I would like to use a GUID as id when Data are inserted instead of a value inside the document. How can I achieve that in the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly , if you just want to ensure the uniqueness of `id` in Cosmos DB, you do not need to create GUID value for it by yourself.

> User-defined unique name of the resource (with the same partition key
>   value). If the user does not specify an id, an id is system generated.

You could see the Cosmos DB System generate items from this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-resources#system-vs-user-defined-resources).

Secondly, if you do want to use GUID as value of id column into cosmos db, you could use [Javascript UDFs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-javascript-user-defined-functions#javascript-user-defined-functions) which is supported by Azure Streaming Job.

My sample `js udfs`:

[image]

Test for query:

[image]

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Can this java script UDF, generate a real GUID? Is there a chance of getting duplicate IDs using this function? May be chances of getting duplicate Id is less, but looks like a probable case.

Comment: Actually, if you don't care about id's rules, you could save these steps because cosmos db will generate id automaticlly if you don't set it. Surely, I provide the js udf in Azure Streaming Job if you does care about the id's rules. For example , you could add time stamp element into id by js udf to ensure uniqueness.